# VMware Guest cannot connect to internet (Firewall)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am trying to get internet access in my guest Ubuntu VMware Workstation 15 Player. I tried multiple tutorials on setting NAT, Bridged connections, etc. but nothing seems to work. I am trying to do this at my workplace which has Trend Micro Deep Security firewall, thus its likely that the firewall is blocking these connections.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to setup the internet to work in VMware in this case?

Comment: Assume you connect your workstation via switch, not directly, install one more PC with Ubuntu installed via the same switch\ - can you set up this Ubuntu for accessing Internet? including IP and another net settings assigning.. If answer is "Yes" then attach virtual NIC as Bridged and set up Ubunty by absolutely the same way.

Comment: You probably should discuss this with your workplace IT staff.